# How do I in a sense "juggle" elements in ndarrays?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, transpose, numpy-ndarray

What I mean by this is imagine you have an ndarray a with shape (2,3,4). I want to define another ndarray b with shape (3,2,4) such that

```
b[i][j][k] = a[j][i][k]
```

Matrix operations only apply to the last 2 index places. If there is a way to make matrix operations act on any 2 chosen index places then everything can be solved.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the same lines of your thought, you can use [`numpy.einsum()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) to achieve what you want.

```
In [21]: arr = np.random.randn(2,3,4)

In [22]: arr.shape
Out[22]: (2, 3, 4)

# swap first two dimensions
In [23]: rolled = np.einsum('ijk->jik', arr)

In [24]: rolled.shape
Out[24]: (3, 2, 4)
```

But pay attention to what you want to do with the resulting array because a *view* of the original array is returned. Thus, if you modify the `rolled` array, the original `arr` will also be affected.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is probably **`np.transpose(..)`** (in fact the transpose of a 2D matrix is a specific case of this):

```
b = a.transpose((1, 0, 2))
```

Here we specify that the first index of the *new matrix* (`b`) is the second (`1`) index of the *old matrix* (`a`); that the second index of the new matrix is the first (`0`) index of the old matrix; and the third index of the new matrix is the third index (`2`) of the old matrix.

This thus means that if `a` has `a.shape = (m, n, p)`, then `b.shape = (n, m, p)`.

Comment: Oh yes thank you! do you know if theres anything similar for matmul, so if i want to do matmul(a,b) but on the first 2 indices :)

Comment: @ZiadFakhoury: but how would you then multiply the vectors? It is a bit unclear what you mean with `a*b` for the first two indexes.

Comment: @ZiadFakhoury: but then the elements of these two indices are *submatrices* (or vectors). How do you then multiply those vectors? Elementwise?

Comment: No you mustve misunderstood me, lets say I had a.shape = (3,2,4) and b.shape =(2,3,4). The long way of doing this would be c = matmul(a.transpose((1,0,2)), b.transpose((1,0,2))).transpose(1,0,2) where c.shape = (3,3,4) and c[:,:,1] = matmul(a[:,:,1], b[:,:,1]) for example

Answer (score 1):

Use [`numpy.rollaxis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.rollaxis.html#numpy.rollaxis):

```
numpy.rollaxis(a, 1)
```